# Scons building with includes from subdirectories

Tags: c++, scons

What code do you have to write in SConstruct file, so that on build all included classes in subdirectories compile? At the moment my SConstruct file looks like this:

```
VariantDir('build', '.')
env=Environment(CPPPATH=['#'],
                CPPDEFINES=[],
                LIBS=['-lpng', '-lassimp', '-lglfw3', '-lGLEW', '-lGLU', '-lGL', '-lX11', '-lXxf86vm', '-lXrandr', '-lpthread', '-lXi'],
                CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11")
env.Program(target='exec_test', source=[Glob('build/*.cpp')])
```

And when i build my project, i get `undefined reference to` errors when calling methods in classes that are in subdirectories. If I move the classes to the root directory, then i get no errors.

Note: building in another directory has nothing to do with this! I tried building in the root directory, but that did not change anything! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SCons Glob()](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) function is ***not*** recursive, so you'll have to add each sub-directory in the source list, as follows:

```
env.Program(target='exec_test', source=[Glob('build/*.cpp'),
                                        Glob('build/subdir1/*.cpp',
                                        Glob('build/subdir2/*.cpp'])
```

This should work, or you could consider creating a hierarchical build whereby you create a SConscript script in each sub-directory.